# How to retrieve and increase fingerprint score in PL/SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper, fingerprint

I am currently using PL/SQL Developer to query a database (Oracle 11g) to generate reports and aggregate data for use. The database collects vital statistics and other bio data such as  DOB, Place of Origin, nationality, parents details, etc.

It also collects an individuals fingerprints and stores them as BLOBs. We use a Hongda S700 Four fingerprint scanner to collect the fingerprints.

The fingerprints are then recorded into the database as BLOBs but also they are given a score; I believe they are called an 'Authentication Threshold Score' from Oracle. These scores indicate whether the fingerprint is qualified, unqualified, are a mismatch or whether the scores need to be increased to qualify the fingerprint.

I am unsure as to what the code is to retrieve the data from the database and how to adjust the score to make the fingerprints qualified. What code (PL/SQL query) do I use to retrieve the fingerprint scores from the database and how do I adjust the scores?

Comment: `select score from fingerprint_table`?

Comment: Is there some fingerprint processing software that you have installed? If so, sample code would help clarify the issue.

Comment: [w]hether the fingerprint "are a mismatch": when matched against what?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson The software that is used in S700 4FingerScan Scanner software on the PC. However when the fingerprints a scanned and uploaded to the database, some fingerprints return with an error statement stating "fingerprint is a mismatch" or "matched with another fingerprint in the database" or the "fingerprint score needs to be increased". Is there a sql statement to search for the fingerprint scores in an Oracle 11g database using Pl/SQL developer?

Comment: Fingerprint matching is not a standard feature of Oracle 11g or PL/SQL Developer, so it will not be possible for anybody to advise you how to use whatever data your application stores in these BLOBs unless you can provide some clues about their structure.